# How to add explanatory text labels to a list of equations / solving steps

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

Does anyone know how to do this in LaTeX and can explain how it is done? The font and design does not matter, what I want is to label the equations.

[image: Example of what should be achieved]

Comment: Hello! Could you please show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have tried and where have you failed? And do you insist on the leading dots?

Comment: You should also edit your question and provide an informative title.

Comment: Are you looking for how to recreate the background texture and shading?

Comment: The Fund does not matter what I want is to label the equations

Comment: @Eliezer Please have a look at [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), epsecially at `align*`. We could give you the solution, but it would be much better if you learn how to solve things yourself :)

Comment: I am guessing that *Fund* is *font*.

Comment: The Fund does not matter what I want is to label the equations.

Comment: `\newcommand*{\oldneg}{\mathord{\sim}}` to get the right negation symbol. (http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/symbols/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @tohecz said, the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package is quite helpful, and learning about it yourself is usually the best solution. The second best solution is seeing what other people have done, taking it, and adjusting it to your needs. Below is a second best solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l c p{6cm} l}
$\neg [(p\Delta q)\to \neg q]$ & $\equiv$ & $\neg[\neg(p\Delta q)\vee\neg q]$ \dotfill & por IMPLICANIA \\
& $\equiv$ & $\neg[\neg(\neg (p\leftrightarrow q))\vee\neg q]$ \dotfill & por ley $(\alpha)$ \\
& $\equiv$ & $\neg[(p\leftrightarrow q)\vee\neg q]$ \dotfill & por DOBLE NEGACION \\
& $\equiv$ & $\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)\wedge \neg\neg q$ \dotfill & por MORGAN \\
& $\equiv$ & $\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)\wedge q$ \dotfill & por DOBLE NEGACION \\
& $\equiv$ & $\neg[(p\wedge q)\vee (\neg p\wedge \neg q)]\wedge q$ \dotfill & por DOBLE IMPLICANCIA \\
& $\equiv$ & $[\neg(p\wedge q)\wedge \neg(\neg p\wedge \neg q)]\wedge q$ \dotfill & por MORGAN \\
& $\equiv$ & $[(\neg p\vee \neg q)\wedge(\neg\neg p\vee \neg\neg q)]\wedge q$ \dotfill & por MORGAN \\
& $\equiv$ & $[(\neg p\vee \neg q)\wedge(p\vee q)]\wedge q$ \dotfill & por DOBLE NEGACION \\
& $\equiv$ & $(\neg p\vee \neg q)\wedge [(p\vee q)\wedge q]$ \dotfill & por ley ASOCIATIVA \\
& $\equiv$ & $(\neg p\vee \neg q)\wedge q$ \dotfill & por ABSORCION \\
& $\equiv$ & $\neg p\wedge q$ \dotfill & por ABSORCION
\end{tabular}\\

Soluci\'on:\ \ $\neg p\wedge q$\ \  RPTA.E

\end{document}
```

Here I have used the `tabular` environment to align the equations and text. I chose `tabular` instead of `align*` because I am not sure how to implement `\dotfill` in `align*`. Either way, this seems to get the job done. Also, I assume the horizontal slightly waved dashes are negation symbols, so I used `\neg` for those, which may not be standard for you. The result is as below.

[image]

Comment: You can cut out a lot of repetition if you use `{>{\(}l<{\)}>{\(\equiv}p{6cm}<{\)\dotfill} l}` as your table preamble.  Then you don't need any dollar signs, you can eliminate the column of `\equiv`, and you don't need to have `\dotfill` in each line.

Comment: This doesn't look quite ok to me. Why is the value of `tabcolsep` exactly 2pt? Shouldn't it be rather medmuskip, or `@{${}\mathrel{}{}}` in the column specs (which would ensure proper spacing around the relation symbol)?

Comment: also, replace `\Delta` by `\mathbin{\Delta}` so it is typset with the space appropriate for a binary operator.

Answer (score 9):

Extending jlv's very good solution, here's one where the input is simpler, because common elements can be implicit.

I also add some macros that help input and make it easier changing the rendering, if needed. So, instead of `\to` and `\leftrightarrow` I define `\limplies` and `\liff` for uniformity with `\lnot`, `\lor` and `\land`. Also, the justification is hidden in a macro (one might want to remove “por”, for example). Instead of all caps, I used small caps that are still noticeable, while not being too evident.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}

\newcommand{\ldel}{\mathbin{\Delta}}
\newcommand{\just}[1]{por \textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\limplies}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\liff}{\leftrightarrow}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{$}l<{$} @{} >{${}}X<{$\dotfill} @{} l @{}}
\lnot [(p\ldel q)\limplies \lnot q]
& \equiv \lnot[\lnot(p\ldel q)\lor\lnot q]                                  & \just{implicancia} \\
& \equiv\lnot[\lnot(\lnot (p\liff q))\lor\lnot q]                           & \just{ley $(\alpha)$} \\
& \equiv \lnot[(p\liff q)\lor\lnot q]                                       & \just{doble negación} \\
& \equiv \lnot(p\liff q)\land \lnot\lnot q                                  & \just{De Morgan} \\
& \equiv \lnot(p\liff q)\land q                                             & \just{doble negación} \\
& \equiv \lnot[(p\land q)\lor (\lnot p\land \lnot q)]\land q                & \just{doble implicancia} \\
& \equiv [\lnot(p\land q)\land \lnot(\lnot p\land \lnot q)]\land q          & \just{De Morgan} \\
& \equiv [(\lnot p\lor \lnot q)\land(\lnot\lnot p\lor \lnot\lnot q)]\land q & \just{De Morgan} \\
& \equiv [(\lnot p\lor \lnot q)\land(p\lor q)]\land q                       & \just{doble negación} \\
& \equiv (\lnot p\lor \lnot q)\land [(p\lor q)\land q]                      & \just{ley asociativa} \\
& \equiv (\lnot p\lor \lnot q)\land q                                       & \just{absorción} \\
& \equiv \lnot p\land q                                                     & \just{absorción}
\end{tabularx}

\nopagebreak\medskip

\hspace*{\fill}Solución: $\lnot p\land q$\qquad RPTA.E\hspace*{2em}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nicely optimized.  Can you put `\just` into the `>` specification for column 3?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang It would be possible, but I prefer not to: a line might have no justification. Likewise, I prefer to leave `\equiv` in the cells, for greater quality.

Answer (score 1):

The output is not what the OP wanted, but package [`tkz-linknodes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-linknodes) is devised to create links between equations and label them.

[image]

This is the code (some commands were taken from egreg's answer)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tkz-linknodes}

\newcommand{\ldel}{\mathbin{\Delta}}
\newcommand{\just}[1]{por \textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\limplies}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\liff}{\leftrightarrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{NodesList}[margin=3cm]
  \begin{displaymath}\displaywidth=.2\linewidth
    \begin{aligned}
   \lnot  [(p\ldel q)\limplies \lnot q] & \AddNode\\
& \equiv \lnot[\lnot(p\ldel q)\lor\lnot q]  \AddNode\\
& \equiv\lnot[\lnot(\lnot (p\liff q))\lor\lnot q]  \AddNode\\
& \equiv \lnot[(p\liff q)\lor\lnot q]                 \AddNode\\                       
& \equiv \lnot(p\liff q)\land \lnot\lnot q      \AddNode\\                           
& \equiv \lnot(p\liff q)\land q                \AddNode\\                            
& \equiv \lnot[(p\land q)\lor (\lnot p\land \lnot q)]\land q     \AddNode\\            
& \equiv [\lnot(p\land q)\land \lnot(\lnot p\land \lnot q)]\land q    \AddNode\\       
& \equiv [(\lnot p\lor \lnot q)\land(\lnot\lnot p\lor \lnot\lnot q)]\land q \AddNode\\
& \equiv [(\lnot p\lor \lnot q)\land(p\lor q)]\land q          \AddNode\\              
& \equiv (\lnot p\lor \lnot q)\land [(p\lor q)\land q]        \AddNode\\               
& \equiv (\lnot p\lor \lnot q)\land q         \AddNode\\                               
& \equiv \lnot p\land q                   \AddNode\\                                   
\end{aligned}
\end{displaymath}
{
\tikzset{LabelStyle/.append style = {right}}
       \LinkNodes{por implicancia}
       \LinkNodes{por ley $(\alpha)$}
       \LinkNodes{por doble negación}
       \LinkNodes{por De Morgan}
       \LinkNodes{por doble negación}
       \LinkNodes{por doble implicancia}
       \LinkNodes{por De Morgan}
       \LinkNodes{por De Morgan}
       \LinkNodes{por doble negación}
       \LinkNodes{por ley asociativa}
       \LinkNodes{por absorción}
       \LinkNodes{por absorción}
}
\end{NodesList}
\nopagebreak\medskip
\hspace*{\fill}Solución: $\lnot p\land q$\qquad RPTA.E\hspace*{2em}
\end{document}
```